# How to upload my own picture to this CV template

Tags: templates, online, overleaf

[Here](https://www.writelatex.com/read/frwbpfqvttzg) is a read-only link to a CV template. It has a little picture in the top left, and I am having trouble finding how to upload my own picture there. How would I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming you're uploading this as a pdf? Then the file will be added locally. Place your photo in the same directory as your .tex file, and change `\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{picture}` to `\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{!your-picture-name-here!}`.

If this is compiled online, same procedure, but upload the picture to your webdirectory and do the same.